# Why parent component doesn't update when save form with spread operator ,but when use "push" it works ..Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

When I Use [...this.characters, this.new] .. in characters.component.html doesn't update the list, but when I use  this.characters.push( this.new) it works ...Why?

```
//add.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Character } from '../interfaces/dbz';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css']
})
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() new: Character = {
    name: '',
    power: 0,
  };
  @Input() characters: Character[] = [];
  save(): void {
    // this.characters= [...this.characters, this.new] Doesn't works :(
    this.characters.push( this.new)


    this.new = {
      name: '',
      power: 0,
    };
  }
  constructor() { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In this form i call my save method

```
//add.component.html
<h3>Add {{ new.name }}</h3>
<hr />
<form (ngSubmit)="save()" action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="new.name" />
  <input
    type="number"
    placeholder="Power"
    name="power"
    [(ngModel)]="new.power"
  />
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

```
///characters.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Character } from '../interfaces/dbz';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-characters',
  templateUrl: './characters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./characters.component.css']
})
export class CharactersComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() characters: Character[] = [];
  constructor() {
   }
   ngOnInit(): void {
   }
}
```

The list doesn't update when use the spread operator ,.. but when I push the new item , add a new character in list

```
//characters.component.html
<h3>Characters</h3>
<hr />
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of characters;debugger">{{ item.name }} - {{ item.power }}</li>
</ul>
```

Here I call my components passing the character and the new character to the form and passing the character to the list html

```
///main-page.component.html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <app-characters [characters]="characters"></app-characters>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <app-agregar [characters]="characters" [new]="new"></app-agregar>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I initialize my character list and my new character

```
//main-page.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Character } from '../interfaces/dbz';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-page',
  templateUrl: './main-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-page.component.css']
})
export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {
  new: Character = {
    name: '',
    power: 0,
  };
  characters: Character[] = [
    {
      name: 'Goku',
      power: 12000,
    },
    {
      name: 'Vegeta',
      power: 7500,
    },
    {
      name: 'Krilin',
      power: 1200,
    },
  ];
  constructor() { 
    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
 
  }

}
```

I need help I don't know why when I push the list .. my character list is updated and when I use spread operator  It does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of memory references.

You start with `MainPageComponent` where you declare an array of characters. We will call this, `memRef0`.

You then send it through an Input, into your components. So `memRef0` is applied to the components inputs. In `AddComponent`, it means that the characters array, which is `memRef1`, points to `memRef0`.

In your `AddComponent`, you do this :

```js
/* 1 */ this.characters= [...this.characters, this.new]
/* 2 */ this.characters.push( this.new)
```

The second line pushes a value in `memRef0`, so it works, the memory reference gets updated.

But the first line, it says that `memRef1` should no point to `memRef0` anymore, but rather to another one, which is `memRef2`.

Since `memRef2` is unknown from MainPage, it doesn't get updated.

To resolve that, either use `push` like you did, or use an `@Output() add = new EventEmitter();` to notify the MainPage of the change, and MainPage will be in charge of updating `memRef0`, which will in turn be propagated to the children components.